# Random Number Generation in Javascript going outside of range

Tags: javascript

My random number generation for my JavaScript program sometimes goes out of bounds from the range that I set.

My code looks like:

```
rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*max)+min;
```

where my max is the upper bound for my number and the min is the lower bound. 
When my min is 1 the code seems to work fine, but if I start at say 10 and have my upper bound at 55 it messes up. In that particular example I sometimes get 57 and so on.

Comment: You're adding min to whatever the random part generates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is all relevant code. Problem is, you do the math random thing, then you shift the whole thing beyond the max. Try this:

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the delta from `max` and `min`.

```
rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the other answers, this will give you an inclusive range:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are getting a wrong result because the formula is wrong.
Try to use

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.floow(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

Documentation [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)