# Why my Math.random method is adding numbers from the range?

Tags: javascript

I want to Pick a random number from the range (100,200) {inclusive} . Why is it adding in between the range.

```
// This will return a Random Number from Given Range

function randomNumberGeneratorInRange(rangeStart, rangeEnd) {
  return Math.random() * rangeEnd + rangeStart;
}
console.log(`My random number: ${randomNumberGeneratorInRange(10, 50)}`);
console.log(`My random number: ${randomNumberGeneratorInRange(100, 200)}`);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25vYy.png)

Comment: `Math.random() * rangeEnd` should be `Math.random() * (rangeEnd - rangeStart)`

Comment: Because `Math.random() * rangeEnd` gives you between `0` and the maximum. If the maximum is `200` and the random number is `180`, you still add the minimum to it making it `280`

Comment: [Random Number Generation in Javascript going outside of range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41942778)

Comment: But this way, it will pick number in difference only. Like (200-100) >> this will not exceed 100 right??

Comment: Replying to VLAZ >> I am adding rangeStart at the end.. this is the full code Math.random() * rangeEnd + rangeStart;

Comment: I think this is the correct code : Math.random() * (rangeEnd - rangeStart) + rangeStart;